# why php-fpm needs load share lib libmysqlclient.so

Tags: php

all:
   I encountered a problem when I start the php-fpm.the problem is :
   /php-fpm: error while loading shared libraries:  libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or  directory
   Actually I googled the problem,hundreds of answers telling you how to handle it,yes,I really fix it according the guideline,but my question is :why starting up php-fpm need to load the libmysqlclient.so.18?and how I can get the info about all the shared libraries for php-fpm need?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have enabled the php mysql extension. If you are on ubuntu, you can disable it with:

`sudo php5dismod php5-mysql php5-mysqlnd`

Of course, if you don't have the mysql extension enabled, you won't be able to call any of the mysql functions from your code.